# Getting a Simple PHP function to run

Tags: php, function

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Invalid argument supplied for foreach() + Logic of Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7925414/invalid-argument-supplied-for-foreach-logic-of-script)

I apologize in advance if my code is a mess.  This is the first time I'm writing with PHP so my methods might not be the most efficient.

I want to make a "sign-up" sheet where the user sees two columns in a table: a time and name column.  Simply, if the user sees an available time, they are able to insert their name into a form and my script will update the page with the time they signed up for.  If the time they are trying to reserve is not available (the block does not read "Available"), the page will notify the user.

My createTable function works -- see this page (http://rich2233.comoj.com/rich2233.php) .  My problem comes in writing to the file, in the function editTxt. I'm stuck on how to proceed with modifying a specific line in the .txt file and modifying it. Could anyone help with getting this program to run?

```
 My .txt looks like this:
 8:00 am|Rich Jones
 9:00 am|Available
 ......
 5:00 pm|Available
```

Most Recent Code:

```
  <?php

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { 
    $find_name = $_POST['name'];
    $find_time = $_POST['time'];
    $filename = getcwd() . "/test.txt";
    $lines = file( $filename , FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES );
foreach($lines as $key => $line)
{
        list($time, $name) = explode('|', $line);
        if($time == $find_time && $name == "Available")
        {
        $lines[$key] = $time."|".$find_name;
        file_put_contents( $filename , $lines );
        break;
  }
  }

  }
// Read the file into an array
$users = file("test.txt");
$hours_taken = array();

// Begin Table
echo "<table align = 'center' border='2' width='50%' cellspacing='0' 
    cellpadding='0'>";
echo "<caption> Sign/Up Sheet </caption>";
echo "<tr><td><b>Time</b></td><td><b>Name</b></td></tr>";

// Cycle through the array
foreach ($users as $user) {

    // Parse the line
    list($time, $name) = explode('|', $user);
array_push($hours_taken, $time);

    // Remove newline 
    $name = trim($name);

    // Output the data in a two column table
    echo "<tr><td>".$time."</td><td>".$name."</td></tr>";

}
echo "</table>";

// Assuming same order of rows in users.txt
$hours = array('8:00 am', '9:00 am', '10:00 am','11:00 am', '12:00 pm', '1:00 pm',  
    '2:00 pm', '3:00 pm', '4:00 pm', '5:00 pm'); 

$i = 1;
echo 'Name:<input type ="text" id="name" name="name" size="20" maxlength="40" />';
echo '<select name="time"><option selected>-- Select time --</option>';
foreach ($hours as $hour) {
if (in_array($hour, $hours_taken)) {
    echo '<option disabled=disabled>'. $hour .'</option>';
}
else {
    echo '<option value='. $i .'>'. $hour .'</option>';
}
$i++;
}

 ?>
 <html>
 <form method="post" action="<?php echo $PHP_SELF;?>">  
 <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Sign Up!" />
 </form>
 </html>
```