# Invalid argument supplied for foreach() + Logic of Script

Tags: php

I posted a similar question earlier today, however I recently downloaded xampp and can now get syntax errors.  I'm very new to all of this.

Please see this example to see the current state of my .php file: http://rich2233.comoj.com/file2.php

I can get the .txt file to extract and display the content from the .txt file, but any attempt of modifying the .txt file does not happen.

When I ran this on xampp, I got this error: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in file2.php on line 30

Comment: Umm...injectability vulnerabilities. I don't really know what to call it since you're using a plaintext file (not good), but you need to sanitize your input. Also, what's actually wrong now with your function? We're not mind readers, you need to tell us exactly what's wrong.

Comment: Use database. Concurrent file modifying without locking could bite you.

Comment: You really want to use a database for this - it'll make your life a lot easier. Look at something called SQLite (http://www.sqlite.org/) which is a flat file database. It may seem like a bit of overhead to learn SQL et al, but it'll be worth learning.

Comment: Guys, the issue here is not why he chooses to use a plaintext-based solution instead of a db storage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After your most recent update of the code: The answer to the error message in the question title is:

The code is missing the line `$users = file("test.txt");`

Comment: That gets rid of the error.  I now have other errors now so I'm going to repost.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a quick tip: keep track of your iterator. Confusing? Think of each row number as unique offset in the file. You need to iterate (`foreach`) and increment it by +1 each time. When you're editing a row later on, you just need to submit the offset number, iterate again and check if `$i == $_POST['iterator']`.

```
// Iterator example
$users = file('text.txt');
$hours_taken = array();

foreach ($users as $user) {
  list($time, $name) = explode('|', $user);
  array_push($hours_taken, $time);
}
// Assuming same order of rows in users.txt
$hours = array('8:00 am', '9:00 am', '10:00 am'); // ...5:00 pm
$i = 1;
echo '<select name="time"><option selected>-- Select time --</option>';
foreach ($hours as $hour) {
  if (in_array($hour, $hours_taken)) {
    echo '<option disabled=disabled>'. $hour .'</option>';
  }
  else {
    echo '<option value='. $i .'>'. $hour .'</option>';
  }
  $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Edited as that last function wouldn't have worked

```
function editTxt(){
  $find_name = $_POST['name'];
  $find_time = $_POST['time'];
  $filename = getcwd() . "/test.txt";
  $lines = file( $filename , FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES );
  foreach($lines as $key => $line)
  {
      list($time, $name) = explode('|', $line);
      if($time == $find_time && $name == "Available")
      {
          $lines[$key] = $time."|".$find_name;
          file_put_contents( $filename , $lines );
          break;
      }
  }
}
```

If you are planning to use this for something other than just an exercise I suggest using a database.

Comment: It's for an exercise.  I put in your code, but the page will not load now.  I do see your logic, but I'm thinking I have an error somewhere.  Any ideas?

Comment: I'm just getting a blank page.  I included  ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
 error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT); in my script, but I'm not getting any syntax errors.  Sorry that I cannot give a better answer. Very new to all of this.

Comment: You should put the call for edit text before create table and don't call create table at the end of edit text. This will result in you writing out two tables!

Comment: Done.  I still get a blank page though.  I updated my question with the most recent code.  I appreciate your help.

Comment: I have changed the function I provided for something better

Comment: Alright! Getting close!  I can now see the table again, BUT when I test to see if the everything works, nothing happens after I press "submit".  The table doesn't seem to change, even if I refresh the page.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$users = file($filename);
```

I suspect $users === false as you aren't using the same "calculated" file name.

Comment: It now gives me this additional error: Filename cannot be empty in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/file2.php on line 21

Comment: Seems like the post submit code isn't executing, then. You could also try $users = file(getcwd() . '/test.txt');

Comment: That does the trick.  Problem now, as you pointed out, is that the submit code isn't executing.  Any ideas why?

Comment: You aren't POSTing a field named "submit", most likely.